# using mirrors to generate a dynamic table

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I've been trying to generate an html table with ng-repeat, without having to know anything about how the data is structured so i used a structure like the following

```dart
    //wraps rows and column defwntions   
    class ItemsCollection{
      List<ColumnDef> ColumnDefs;
      List<DynamicItem> Items;
      ItemsCollection(this.ColumnDefs,this.Items);
    }

    //represents a column 
    class ColumnDef{
      int id;
      String name,displayName,tableName;
      bool isPrimaryKey,isNumeric,isCalculated;
      ColumnDef({this.name,this.displayName,this.tableName,this.isPrimaryKey,this.isNumeric,this.isCalculated});
    }

    //represents a data row ,since i don't know how the structure of the data looks like before run time the following class adds properties dynamically if they are not defined
    class DynamicItem{
      Map<String,Object> properties;

      DynamicItem([Map<String,Object> initialProperties]){
          this.properties = initialProperties == null ? new Map<String,Object>() : initialProperties;
        }

      noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation){
        if(invocation.isAccessor){
          final realName = MirrorSystem.getName(invocation.memberName);
          if(invocation.isSetter){
            final name = realName.substring(0,realName.length - 1);
            properties[name] = invocation.positionalArguments.first;
            return null;
          } else {
            return properties[realName];
          }
        }
        return super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
      }
    }

//and a part of simple angular directive to render the table
@Component(
    selector: 'table-component',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    template: '''<button ng-click="ctrl.addClalculatedCoulmn()">Add Calculated Column</button>
                <table border=2px}">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                         <th ng-repeat="col in ctrl.ItemsSource.ColumnDefs">{{col.displayName}}</th>
                       <tr>
                    </thead>
                     <tbody>
                       <tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.ItemsSource.Items">
                         <td ng-repeat="col in ctrl.ItemsSource.ColumnDefs">
                            {{item.properties[col.name]}}
                         </td>
                       </tr>
                    </tbody>
                 </table>'''
)
class TableComponent {
  ItemsCollection ItemsSource;

  TableComponent(){
      ItemsCollection = service.getItemsCollection();
  };

  void addCalculatedCoulmn(string MathmaticlExpression){
     //adds a new column to the defentions
     //adds a new property to each row
  }
}
```

which is perfect but kind of slow, my main goal was about adding calculated coulmns at run time + not having to worry about writing my models , i want to build a grid control over this, but i am not sure if this is the best solution, and i tested it over 20000 data objects that has 6 properties + 2 calculated ones, and it took 37 seconds and i am not really sure why its slow, any suggestions to make it faster or any ideas to avoid using reflection and keep it dynamic?

i am using dart on the server side too, and i want to make sure that i am not missing out on any concepts that help me achieve such things, performance is what matters the most except i don't want to represent the data in models by hand, i would appreciate any ideas you have.

Comment: Mirrors are slow and lead to code bloat when built to JavaScript. Why do you not know how the data is structured. Maybe there is another approach possible?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i simply want to build a dashboard where i can view the data and group it and visualize it and add coulmns to it that are calculated at run time based on other columns, problem is if i were to write models i will end up with hundreds of them

Comment: When you put all your data in Maps and Lists, you could check if a map contains some id and change the behavior based on that knowledge 
or you could also use 'x is Type' checks without mirrors. You could create a few interfaces that your classes have to implement in order to be supported by your component which could be used to check for 'is Interface'.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but still i can't really wrap my head around way to make a model have properties without mirrors other than writing it by hand! thats the only thing i miss about javascript, i will rewrite it in javascript and see how it performs

Comment: You are right, if the properties have arbitrary names its difficult/impossible. There are plans to improve this in Dart but don't expect an improvment anytime soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing something similar in a prototype recently; and ended up just including the field names etc. in the data structure (it was coming from a server as JSON).

My data looked like this:

```dart
class ClientGrid {
  List<ClientGridColumn> cols;
  List<List<Object>> data;
  int currentPage;
  int totalPages;
  int totalRecords;
  int recordsPerPage;
}

class ClientGridColumn {
  String name;
  bool visible;
}
```

And the code like this:

```dart
var table = new TableElement();
table.className = "table table-hover";

var headerRow = table.createTHead().addRow();
data.cols.forEach((c) {
  if (c.visible)
    headerRow.append(new Element.tag('th')..text = c.name);
});

var body = table.createTBody();

data.data.forEach((r) {
  var row = body.addRow();
  r.asMap().forEach((i, c) {
    var col = data.cols[i];
    if (!col.visible)
      return;

    var cellContents = new SpanElement()
          ..text = c.toString();

    row.addCell().children.add(cellContents);
  });
});

this.children.add(table);
```